# how can I move to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, segue

I have a problem with `indexPathForSelectedRow()`

I have 2 viewcontroller: 
tableview and view controller

I want to move from tableview to another controller

and I used func `prepareForSegue` but I have problem in `indexpathselectedrow()`

This is issue for the problem:

> **cannot invoke "indexpathforselectedRow" with no arguments**

The Xcode is a last version

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "show"
    {
        let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let detailvc: fiveViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! fiveViewController

    }

}
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: &&&  this is issue for the problem " cannot invoke "indexpathforselectedRow" with no arguments  "

Comment: Can you show `tableView` definition?

Comment: how can I get the definition ?

Comment: Ha! Are you using Xcode 7?

Comment: no , it's 6.3 version

Answer (score 1):

There is the `indexPathForSelectedRow` definition in **Swift 1.2**:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow;                                                // returns nil or index path representing section and row of selection.
```

There is its definition in **Swift 2.0**:

```
var indexPathForSelectedRow: NSIndexPath? { get } // returns nil or index path representing section and row of selection.
```

In Swift 2.0, the `indexPathForSelectedRow` is a property not a method, so you should change:

```
let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

to

```
let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Comment: i solved I added " UITableViewController" and solved it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no reference to `tableView` or it's not of type `UITableView`.

Comment: I have tableview and I want to go another view controller If I pressed on the a Row , and indexpathselectedrow not working , and And shows me
 " cannot invoke "indexpathforselectedRow" with no arguments "

Comment: It's hard to determine how you created your segue or how you're calling it. Are you calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: no , I calling in :  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue , sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show"
    {
        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()!
        let detailv:fiveViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! fiveViewController
        detailv.pic = self.menu[indexpath.row].picName 

    }
```

this link for the pic " my problem "

[image]

Comment: You can post a new question

Comment: my problem in in [indexpath.row] it's not working , please see for the link picture in up question

Comment: The `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns `[AnyObject]?` not `NSIndexPath?`. Change `let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()!` to `let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()! `